# Is there a way to check if the user clicks the wrong circle from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, p5.js

I'm making a game in p5.js in which you have to find the darker circle in a group of randomly placed circles. When you click on the correct one, it re-randomizes everything and you go again. The positions of the circles are placed in an array that randomizes at the start of each "round." I need a way to see if the player clicks an incorrect circle so it removes a life (which haven't implemented yet)

This is the code:

```js
function setup() { 
  createCanvas(600, 450);
  background(255);
  circles = [];

  circleNum = 50
  r = random(0, 240)
  g = random(0, 240)
  b = random(0, 240)
  
  while (circles.length != circleNum+1) {
    noStroke();
    fill(70, 150, 200, 200)
    
    var overlapping = false;
    
    var circle = {
      x: random(width),
      y: random(height),
      r: 20
    }
    
    for (var j = 0; j < circles.length; j++) {
      var prev = circles[j];
      var circlesDist = dist(circle.x, circle.y, prev.x, prev.y);
      
      if (circlesDist < circle.r + prev.r) {
        overlapping = true;
      } else if (circle.x < circle.r || circle.x > width-circle.r) {
        overlapping = true;
      } else if (circle.y < circle.r || circle.y > height-circle.r) {
        overlapping = true;
      }
    }
    
    if (!overlapping) {
      circles.push(circle);
    }
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    fill(r, g, b, 200);
    ellipse(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, circles[i].r*2, circles[i].r*2);
  }
  
  fill(r, g, b, 200);
  ellipse(circles[circleNum].x, circles[circleNum].y, circles[circleNum].r*2, circles[circleNum].r*2);
}

function mousePressed() {
  if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, circles[circleNum].x, circles[circleNum].y) < circles[circleNum].r) {
    setup();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I really have no idea of how I would go about this so if anyone can help, I'm all ears.

Comment: How do you define a circle as "wrong" or not? Right now, they all look like the same color. I'd start by picking a wrong circle based on your conditions, then in your loop, determine if the circle `i` you're comparing against is "wrong" or not. Basically something as simple as `const wrongIndex = floor(random(circles.length))`. Render that one a bit darker than the others. Later on, in your loop `if (i === wrongIndex) { /* skip distance check, or whatever you want to do */ }`.

Comment: I don't know if this is a reply to ggorlen's comment but there is one circle that is a little bit darker than the others, sometimes it's just difficult to find, and that one is the only correct circle.

Comment: All circles use the exact same `fill()` call: `fill(r, g, b, 200);`. `r`, `g`, `b` values never change. You may have meant for the last `fill()` call to use something other than 200 as the alpha. If so, feel free to [edit] your post to update the code. If so, my approach suggested above should still work: `if (i === circleNum) { /* here's the dark one, do whatever */ }`.

Comment: Yes but there is one more circle below the final for loop that overlaps one of the previous circles, effectively increasing the alpha value, making it more visible. I want to make it so that if you click any other circle (not when you don't click the correct circle) it makes that circle shake to indicate that it isn't the right one. Could there be a way to skip drawing the bottom circle and just increase the alpha value of the correct one?

Comment: I see, you're right. Well, the same answer applies, `circleNum` is your target, so you can use either `===` or `!==` to run your logic wherever you need it. Sure, you can use one `fill()` if you want, again, use a condition or change the loop variable to be one less, then change the final `fill()` call. I guess I'm missing where the difficulty here is. In fact, you already have the condition that calls `setup()` when the darker one is clicked, so all you need to do is add an `else {}` and decrement a life there.

Comment: Oh! Could I do something like this: `for (var i = 0; i != circleNum; i++) {...}` instead of `for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {...}`

Comment: No, that condition is the same pretty much. You could use `i < circles.length - 1` to skip the last circle, but I wouldn't worry about it, you already have correct logic. I was mistaken in thinking all circles were the same. I don't mean to distract you from the main question.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is it possible to make every circle their own variable so that I can animate them separately?

Comment: Generally, no, you'd loop over the array and animate them collectively. If you want circle 0 to do something totally distinct from all other circles, you can always use `circle[0]` directly instead of `const circle0 = circle[0]`.

Comment: Hmm. Could I draw them so they don't intersect but they are their own variable? Like could I use the array just to define their positions but draw them separately?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking or what your requirements are for the animation, exactly, but maybe ask a new question if you're trying to do something totally different from what you're asking about here, which is implementing "lives". When you ask, I'd focus less on your ideas for the solution and more on the problem you're trying to solve. What animation are you trying to implement, before jumping into how you think you'll implement it? In many cases, the solution will be [different than you assume](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Comment: I may have an idea. I'll edit the snippet if it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I'd start by keeping it as is and answering this question, then opening a new question if you have something else to ask. This is important because the thread may be useful to future visitors with the same problem as you--the goal here is to curate a Q&A resource for searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you already have all of the necessary logic--it's just a matter of adding a lives counter and an `else {}` on your distance check:

```js
let lives;

function setup() {
  // ...
  lives = 3;
}

function mousePressed() {
  if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, circles[circleNum].x, circles[circleNum].y) < circles[circleNum].r) {
    setup();
  } else {
    // the user has clicked elsewhere than the target circle; remove a life
    lives--;

    if (lives === 0) {
      // the user has lost all lives; do something special
    }
  }
}
```

As an aside, always declare your variables with `let` or `const` to avoid clashing with `window` variables. If you do `foo = 42` without a `let` or `const` anywhere, it's added to the global scope.

Also, generally never call `setup()`--this is called by p5 for you and should be one-off canvas creation and so forth. I've written custom functions, added lives and removed some redundant tests:

```js
const circlesToMake = 50;
let circles, r, g, b, lives;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 450);
  background(255);
  noStroke();
  setupCircles();
  drawCircles();
}

function setupCircles() {
  circles = []
  lives = 3;
  r = random(0, 240)
  g = random(0, 240)
  b = random(0, 240)

  while (circles.length < circlesToMake) {
    const circle = {
      x: random(width),
      y: random(height),
      r: 20
    };
    let overlapping = false;

    for (let j = 0; j < circles.length; j++) {
      const other = circles[j];
      const d = dist(circle.x, circle.y, other.x, other.y);

      if (d < circle.r + other.r) {
        overlapping = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!overlapping) {
      circles.push(circle);
    }
  }
}

function drawCircles() {
  clear();
  circles.forEach(c => {
    fill(r, g, b, 200); ellipse(c.x, c.y, c.r * 2, c.r * 2);
  });

  fill(0, 0, 0, 200); // make the target easy to identify for development purposes
  const target = circles[0];
  ellipse(target.x, target.y, target.r * 2, target.r * 2);
  text(`lives: ${lives}`, 20, 20);
}

function mousePressed() {
  if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, circles[0].x, circles[0].y) < circles[0].r) {
    setupCircles();
    drawCircles();
  } else {
    if (--lives === 0) {
      setupCircles();
    }

    drawCircles();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

For simplicity, I treat `circles[0]` as the target/darker circle.

If you only want to decrement a life if the user has clicked on a valid dot rather than whitespace, you can loop over all circles to make sure at least one is being touched in the `mousePressed` `else` block:

```js
const anyClicked = circles.some(c => dist(mouseX, mouseY, c.x, c.y) < c.r);

if (anyClicked && --lives === 0) {
  // ...
```

Other game reset behavior is possible, like carrying lives forward from one round to another, showing "game over" screens, etc, but these are out of scope of the immediate problem.

Comment: This is great, thank you for cleaning up my code, but I was looking for more of a way  wherein if the user clicks on a circle that isn't the darker circle, they lose a life. This just makes it so that if the user doesn't click on the circle, they lose a life. Do you think there could be a way to do that?

Comment: The post discusses this: "If you only want to decrement a life if the user has clicked on a valid dot rather than whitespace, you can loop over all circles to make sure at least one is being touched in the `mousePressed` else block." I suggest attempting the suggestions in my comments; I'm trying to help guide you to the answers rather than giving you the solution outright, since if you have the skill to write the code you posted, it's a small step to implementing your requests (adding a condition and loop or two, basically).